# Angular 5 and Firestore Nested Object

Tags: json, angular, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestorm collection with this structure:

```
USERID {
    email: "test@test.com"
    name: "John Doe"
    roles{
        user: true
        editor: true
        admin: false
    }
}
```

I am able to get this data as a collection and render it in the view.

component.ts:

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

this.userCollection = this.afs.collection('users')
this.users = this.userCollection.valueChanges()
```

component.html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let user of users | async;>
      <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.roles }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.job }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Everything displays correctly except "roles" which displays as [object Object]

I can get roles to display by changing the line to

```
{{ user.roles | json }}
```

but that only displays the raw json data. How can I display the roles that are set to true? Is there a better way to structure my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

role is object too. i you can get the property like this

```
 <tr *ngFor="let user of users | async;>
  <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.roles.user }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.job }}</td></tr>
```

Comment: Is there a way to display the keys that are set to true?

Comment: you can try like this
`<td *ngIf="user.roles.user">{{ user.roles.user }}</td>`